# regex to color all tags in blue

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code

```
<products>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Apple iPhone 7</name>
        <price currency="EUR">79.00</price>
    </product>
</products>
```

I want to do a preg replace for all the tags so for example:

```
<products>
```

has to become

```
<<span class="blue" draggable="true">products</span>>
```

I also want to match attributes.

How can I achieve this with a regular expression?

This one works partly:

```
$xml = preg_replace('/&lt;(.*)&gt;(.*)&lt;\/(.*)&gt;/','&lt;<span class="highlight-blue" draggable="true">$1</span>&gt;$2&lt;<span class="highlight-blue" draggable="true">$3</span>&gt;',$xml);
```

The problems with this one are:

- the "main" tag 'products' is not colored blue, the other tags are
- i doesn't match the 'currency="EUR"' in the price tag

Comment: What do you mean color the tag names and not the value?

Comment: if i have the tags <id>1</id> then I want "id" and "\id" in blue, but "1", "<" and ">" stays in black.

Comment: Can you update your question to have an example of what your desired output would be?

Comment: Are you ultimately just trying to do syntax highlighting?

Comment: yes and i want to make the tags draggable with draggable="true"

Comment: What have you tried? I see no effort on your part

Comment: I have tried a lot but I don't make sense posting crappy regexes that don't work... I'll post some in my question the ones i tried...

Comment: Don't go about this with regex, use a proper XML parser, and then loop through the resulting DOM to build the HTML structure you need to reflect it. (And are you sure you want the spans _inside_ the <>? So that the user can drag the _tag name_ of an XML element shown to them, but not the tag (or the element) itself ...?

Comment: yes the user must drag the tag names (not the values)! Do you know a proper xml parser? I've searched a lot on google but I cant' find anything!

Comment: [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)